# Animation lost on applying Displace Modifier on plane with Plane Axis as coordinate

Tags: animation, modifiers

Created a plane added a displace modifier and on texture I have set type as cloud and size(2.3) and depth(0) then I have set coordinate as object and selected Plane axis, so when we try to rotate the plane axis it creates some wave like effects but when I try to apply the modifier the plane axis is not anymore linked to the plane due which I loose my animation[image]

Comment: That is what happens when you apply a modifier

Comment: I'm new to blender so is there any way I can export the animation with modifers. I need the export in gltf or glb format

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92187/how-do-i-bake-animation-for-exporting-animation-created-by-wave-modifier https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35339/exporting-animation-with-modifier https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30310/how-to-apply-the-ocean-modifier-to-get-an-animated-object https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218511/export-object-with-modifier-animation-as-gltf-file